# Critical Region for when testing several restrictions using F-test

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

In the classical linear regression setting, when we want to test $H_0: \beta_r=0$ ($\beta_r$ is a vector of dim. $r$) versus $H_1: \beta \neq 0$, we usually use an F-Statistic.

With these two-sided hypothesis I would expect a rejection region of the form $\mathbb{R} \setminus \left[ F_{r,n-k}^{-1}(\alpha/2),F_{r,n-k}^{-1}(1-\alpha/2) \right]$.

However, it seems that we're supposed to compute the p-values, rejection region, etc as if we were in the presence of one-sided hypothesis.

Why is that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When $p=2$, the confidence region is ellipsoidal. The test statistic (of a Wald test) is an increasing function of the distance from the origin. Under the null, the test stat takes an F distribution which is strictly positive. A 0 is achieved directly at the center of the ellipse, which is *most* consistent with the null hypothesis. So you wouldn't reject a hypothesis w/ a test stat in the "lower" region, that's silly.

Comment: @AdamO I'm not sure I understand your comment...I understand everything except the last sentence and its relationship with the rest.

Comment: Ah... now I think I understand @AdamO. After reading the comment by GregSnow below. How do you show that the wald test  is written as the distance from the origin? I think it's related to your answer with the quadratic formula. But I would like it to see it more explicit, please.

Comment: @AdamO Also, what's the point at the center of the elipse? The $H_0$ values or the estimates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notationally, we use $p$ to denote the dimensionality of the parameter space usually, and not $r$.

You are not testing multiple hypotheses, you are testing one hypothesis: that is whether any of the $\vec{\beta}$ parameters is non-zero. The critical region is defined on the real line because the statistical significance of the parameters is summarized with an $f: \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ mapping, such as $W = \hat{\beta}^T \mbox{Cov} \left(\hat{\beta}\right) \hat{\beta}$ which has an approximate $\chi^2_p$ distribution.

So in multivariate tests the confidence region is ellipsoidal which is non-oriented. In the $p=2$ case, quadrant 1 indicates a (+, -) relationship, quadrant 2 indicates a (-, -) relationship and so on. You can construct 1 sided tests for multiple parameters as long as they occupy a compact region of the parameter space. For instance, you can't set the null region to the (-, -) $\cup$ (+, +) region. Without spouting advanced theory, this "breaks" tests.

This commonly occurs (but not exclusively) in ANOVA settings where the interest lies in the difference in means between groups. The downside of such tests is that one cannot conclude that a significant result indicates *which* value is heterogeneous, or the direction of difference. To address this, multiple testing is often applied. A *post-hoc* test concerns subsequently testing for differences in all but one of the $p$ parameters apart from the grand mean. Corrections for multiple testing must be applied to confidence intervals, and either $p$-values (for Fisherian testing) or critical regions (for Neyman Pearson testing).

To put a point on it, here is a picture. You have a donut indicating the central (null hypothesis consistent) region and an outer region and inner torus representing the right tail and left tail reject regions of the F distribution. The left tail (small valued F) actually *contains* the null hypothesized region.

See my comment at the top of the post and view the following graphics. There is no test statistic which accounts for the directionality of the parameters that will lead you to a good test.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, could you 'spout' that advanced theory, and give references?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I define a test which is not consistent to be broken. With disjoint subsets of the support, $\mathbf{\Xi} = \Xi_0 \cup \Xi_1$, a minimal assumption for a test is that the power goes to 1 when $\theta \in \Xi_1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and 0 otherwise *unless* $\theta$ happens to be a boundary, in which the power is allowed to be in the range of $(0, 1)$ (independent of $n$). This is the Karlin Rubin theorem. Basically a test statistic should lead to a partially ordered parameter space.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. In a more general testing framework, I think you can show that defining confidence regions on the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane (and not transforming the test statistic according to, say, it's product, is not minimax because there are admissible estimators with less risk. I admit I don't recall this theory *too* well, but some good discussion are in Hodges and Lehmann theory of point estimation.

Comment: (+1) in your answer, and in the comments at the top. If you could introduce that comment and then tie it with your answer, I would accept your answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's in the nature of the testing.  With a simple test like the t-test you can test a less than case, a greater than case, or the 2 tailed case.  But with the F test (and others) any deviation from the null will make the statistic larger (think of taking the absolute value (or squaring) of the t-statistic, now all values are positive and the values away from 0 will reject the hypothesis) so we only look at the higher values.  In fact, it is difficult (both conceptually and computationally) to do a one sided alternative with an F test, except in a few specific cases.

If you see an F-statistic near 0 this means that the variation between the means, or the variation of the coefficients away from 0, is smaller than would be expected.  This can happen by chance when the null is true, or can be due to assumptions not holding (an F-statistic near 0 can be a red flag to double check all the assumptions and other conditions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Greg. Could please elaborate a bit more as to why the reasoning valid for the case of $r=1$ (using the notation of my question)  of equating a squared t-stat to an F-stat should also be valid, or can be translated to the case of $r>1$?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. In the case of one coefficient the F-statistic is exactly equal to the t-statistic squared.  So rejecting a t-stat less than the negative critical value or rejecting the t-stat greater than the critical value is exactly the same as rejecting the squared t-stat being greater than the squared critical value (which is the F-dist critical value).  Rejecting the F when it is below a given critical value (near 0) would be the same as rejecting a t-statistic that is close to 0 (the case that is most consistent with the null).

Comment: I understood your example for one-dimension. I was asking was how do you know that the intuition for one-dimensional case still applies to the multi-dimensional case. (+1) for your intuition in the answer ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. If all of the coefficient estimates are 0, then the F-statistic will be 0 as well.  As any of the coefficient estimates move away from 0 (in either direction) the F-statistic increases (moves away from 0 in the positive direction).